# How can I split a column with nested delimiters into a list of STRUCTs in Bigquery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got a column that has entries (variable numbers of 2-tuples) like this:

`D000001:Term1;D00007:Term19;D00008:Term781` (`mesh_terms` column below) and I'd like to split those so that I end up with an `ARRAY<STRUCT<code STRING, term STRING>>` for each row.

The query below works as needed, but I'm curious if anyone has suggestions on improvements in terms of readability, performance (on Bigquery, so not too big a problem), or best practices.

```
with t1 as (
SELECT 
  pmid, 
  split(mesh_terms, ';') as l1  
FROM `omicidx_etl.pm1`
),
t2 as (
  select 
    t1.pmid, 
    x 
  from t1, 
    unnest(t1.l1) as x
),
t3 as (
select 
  pmid, 
  split(x, ':') as y 
from t2
)
select 
  pmid, 
  array_agg(STRUCT(t3.y[offset(0)] as code, t3.y[offset(1)] as term)) as mesh_terms 
from 
  t3 
group by pmid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select pmid, 
  array(
    select as struct split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] code, split(kv, ':')[safe_offset(1)] term
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(mesh_terms, r'[^:;]+:[^:;]+')) kv
  ) mesh_terms
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data like in your question - output is

[image]